# Is it possible to use the isWholeLine decorator option for just a single decoration?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm working on an extension for vscode highlighting formatting errors (according to my school's norm), but I would like to highlight the entire line when an error is an empty line in the wrong place. 
For other errors, I just want to highlight the specific text causing the error.

So in short, when there is an empty line in the wrong place, I want to highlight the whole line, otherwise, I want normal highlighting.

From what I understand, the `isWholeLine` decorator option only works in a `TextEditorDecorationType`, and can not be added in `renderOptions` for a specific decoration in a decoration set.
Am I correct in that conclusion or am I just using this wrong?

I got it working for all decorations by adding `isWholeLine` in my `TextEditorDecorationType`, but since I want it only for specific types of errors that's not good enough. I also tried this for the empty line errors:

```ts
decoration = {
    range: range,
    hoverMessage: "**" + e.fullText + "**",
    renderOptions: {
        isWholeLine: true,
    },
};
```

but that didn't do anything. any tips how i could still achieve this?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Why not create two `TextEditorDecorationType`,  one for the empty line error and has `isWholeLine` as true, and another one for other errors?